# Filter Cubeset based on dimension & measure

Tags: excel, mdx, olap-cube

I have a created a cube with different tables - Product Master,Sales Details,Calendar table.

I want to apply filter to cubeset function of Excel, using MDX expression.

I'm confused & result are not appropriate. I want to filter set based on both Dimension & Measure.

What to use? Filter/Exist/Existing?

```
=CUBESET(
"ThisWorkbookDataModel",
"EXISTS(
    FILTER(
       [Basepack].[Basepack].children,
       [Measures].[GM%]>0.5
    ),
    (
      [Calendar].[Month].["&$C$5&"],
      [Cluster_Region].[Cluster].[INDIA],
      [Channel].[Channel].[MT]
    )
)"
,"All Bps"
)
```

It is not giving me the desired result. I want list/set of Basepack with GM%>50% with filter on dimensions.

Comment: Is it throwing an error or returning the wrong results? If the results are wrong then can you add why they are wrong please.

Answer (score 0):

Best place to start is not with either `Exist or Existing` but rather `NonEmpty`:

```
=CUBESET(
"ThisWorkbookDataModel",
"NONEMPTY(
    FILTER(
       [Basepack].[Basepack].children,
       [Measures].[GM%]>0.5
    ),
    {(
      [Calendar].[Month].["&$C$5&"],
      [Cluster_Region].[Cluster].[INDIA],
      [Channel].[Channel].[MT]
    )}
)"
,"All Bps"
)
```